# React native app connection problem with digital ocean managed database

Tags: react-native, digital-ocean

I am creating an web and mobile app for my restaurant. I have rent digital ocean managed database as well to store data. The web app is working well but I can’t send post request from my react native app which is under development. We can easily give access our droplet and ips to database as trusted source but how can I connect it with my react native app which is under development.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a local API (http://localhost:3000/deposit)
just remove it and use live API.

react-native not supported localhost API. >>>
you should use a live API like (https://myapi.com/deposit)

then it will work. and you could store data in your database

Comment: Yes, Its using the life API